# Does the matching of cluster endpoints change if the role of the rds instance changes?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

rds instance was scaled up. (Duplicated)
The two instances were run at different times.
After the scale-up was complete, the roles(write/read-only) of the two instances were reversed.

Does the cluster endpoint rematch if the role of the matched instance changes?

If rematching occurs on the cluster endpoint, we try to apply it to the server settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Translated from [Cluster Endpoint](https://linux.systemv.pe.kr/aws-aurora-endpoint-and-was-connection-pool/):

> Cluster Endpoint provides automatic failover for read/write access. If a problem occurs with the primary instance, one of the replica instances is selected as the primary instance. The cluster endpoint discards the domain of the existing primary instance using DNS and changes to the replica instance. By doing this, the Cluster Endpoint domain address remains unchanged. The replica instance designated as the new primary instance in the cluster endpoint is promoted to the primary instance for the read/write role.